# NASM mov doesn't work correctly

Tags: nasm, mov

I want to get two numbers and do division.
But it keeps throwing Float Point exception, so I used gdb to debug and I found that when I store value to rax, its high bits are 'corrupted'.

When [num] is 20d, 0x2800000014 is stored at rax.

When [num] is 40d, 0x1400000028 is stored.

I guess some of its high bit is currupted(?) when I store them. What's the problem?

```
section .data
    in:     db "%d %d", 0
    len:    equ $-in

section .bss
    num:    resd 2

section .text

main:
    mov     rdi, in
    mov     rsi, num
    mov     rdx, num + 4
    xor     rax, rax
    call    scanf

    mov     rax, [num] ; ------------- here
    mov     rdx, [num + 4]
    idiv    rdx

    ...

    xor     rax, rax
    ret
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're scanning for two `int`s, and they are stored as two 32-bit integers (4 bytes apart) starting at address `num`.

Hence, when you try to read 64 bits from that location you get both 32-bit values. 0x14 == 20, and 0x28 is the other value you entered.

You should be able to replace `mov rax, [num]` with `mov eax, [num]` (and similarly for `rdx`). This will automatically clear the most significant 32 bits of those registers.

---

Note that `IDIV r/m64` divides `RDX:EAX` (the 128-bit octaword formed by `rdx` and `rax`) by the divisor.
So it's not a good idea to use `rdx` as the divisor, since that means you will be dividing `0xkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm` by `0xkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkk`, giving you a quotient of `0x0000000000000001nnnnnnnnnnnnnnnn`. Since the valid range for the quotient is `−2^63` to `2^63 − 1` you'll get a Divide Error because of an out-of-range quotient.

---

tl;dr: you should be able to fix this by changing the 3 lines of code after `call scanf` to:

```
mov     eax, [num]
cqo                     ; sign-extend rax into rdx
mov     ebx, [num + 4]  ; <-- note, ebx instead of edx
idiv    rbx             ; <-- note, rbx instead of rdx
```

Or, since both your dividend and divisor is 32-bit, you could use `IDIV r/m32` which will [likely be faster](http://www.agner.org/optimize/instruction_tables.pdf):

```
mov     eax, [num]
cdq                     ; sign-extend eax into edx
mov     ebx, [num + 4]  
idiv    ebx
```

(`cdq`/`cqo` fills `edx`/`rdx` with the sign-bit of `eax`/`rax`)